# Why the declarations of a function are mismatching in my VScode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm writing python script in my VScode.

> VScode version:1.43
>
> OS: windows
>
> python extension:2020.2.64397

[Detailed Version imformation of VScode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rzew.png)

I `import torch` and use `torch.max()`

The problem i'm facing is that the declarations of a function shows differently. When i move my mouse on the name of the function, it shows the mismatching declaration and i cannot change it!

[different declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxI5p.png)

Also, when i try `go to the declaration` or `peek declaration` or `go to the definition`, **__init__.pyi** will show up but only with the cursor at the beginning.

I don't know what it is related to. Is there something i should do or configure, or is more information needed to solve it?

Comment: It sounds like you may have assigned something to `torch`.

Comment: Oh you remind me of that! i have tried to disable something and finally i find what caused my problem. i installed the extension **Visual Studio Intellicode** which adds a line `"python.jediEnabled": false`in my setting.json, which also causes different rows in my own declarations to appear in one line. Should it be something i could configure to solve or a bug to report? Thanks. @user2357112supportsMonica

Comment: `"python.jediEnabled"` controls whether you use Jedi or the Microsoft Language Server for auto-complete. Each of them will result in different doc hints and such.